# Xamarin Left margin in iPad

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I face strange behavior when I am populate list view all cells have left margin

tested Device iPad 9 in simulator , iPad 12 in simulator

here is screen of my issue [image] 
and my second list 
[image]

here is my Xaml

```
 <customRender:ExtList x:Name="listViewFlights" BackgroundColor ="{StaticResource white_color}" 
                      ItemTapped="ListView_OnItemTapped" SeparatorColor="Gray" SeparatorVisibility="Default"  
                      MinimumHeightRequest="40" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" Refreshing="ListViewFlights_Refreshing"  >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <customRender:CustomViewCell >
                            <StackLayout  Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="Aqua">

                                <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"   x:Name="gridCell"  RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3.25*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4.75*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstListColumn}" Style="{StaticResource GridItemStyleLabelStart_os}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Padding="{Binding FlightListColumn2Padding}" VerticalOptions="Center"  >
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Dep_Dest}" Style="{StaticResource GridItemStyleLabel_os}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  RowSpacing="0" >
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  IsVisible="{Binding IsRecalculated}"  Padding="0" Margin="0,7" OutlineColor="#5C768E" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                        <Label  Text="R" Style="{StaticResource GridItemStyleLabelStart}"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  IsVisible ="{Binding IsRecalculated}"  />
                                        </Frame>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ATCCtot }" Style="{StaticResource GridItemStyleLabelStart}" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding PreparedStd}" Style="{StaticResource GridItemStyleLabelEnd_os}" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"  />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <BoxView x:Name="SelectedBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"  Opacity="{Binding IsSelected}" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource sub_header}" >
                                        <BoxView.WidthRequest>
                                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="5"  />
                                        </BoxView.WidthRequest>
                                    </BoxView>

                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </customRender:CustomViewCell>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </customRender:ExtList>
```

**my tries to fix the issue :**

after long search I find soluation in xamarin site , is to make custom render to my list view but it docent work

```
 public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);
            if (e.NewElement != null) {
                var listView = Control as UITableView;
                listView.CellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

reference https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/viewcell/

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60636) that is in the process of being fixed.